# Checking if subfolders exist linux

Tags: linux, posix-api

I'm trying to check if a folder has any subfolders without iterating through its children, in Linux. The closest I've found so far is using `ftw` and stopping at the first subfolder - or using `scandir` and filtering through the results. Both, are, however, an overkill for my purposes, I simply want a yes/no.

On Windows, this is done by calling `SHGetFileInfo` and then testing `dwAttributes & SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER` on the returned structure. Is there such an option on Linux?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the implementation of SHGetFileInfo on Windows? Does it not simply iterate the directory entries anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard answer is to call [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on the directory, then check the st_nlink field ("number of hard links").  On a standard filesystem, each directory is guaranteed to have 2 hard links (`.` and the link from the parent directory to the current directory), so each hard link beyond 2 indicates a subdirectory (specifically, the subdirectory's `..` link to the current directory).

However, it's my understanding that filesystems aren't required to implement this (see, e.g., [this mailing list posting](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-developers/2008-04/msg00112.html)), so it's not guaranteed to work.

Otherwise, you have to do as you're doing:

1. Iterate over the directory's contents using [glob](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) with the GNU-specific `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag, or [scandir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scandir), or [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).
2. Call [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) on each result and check `S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)` to verify that files found are directories.  Or, nonportably, check `struct dirent.d_type`: if it's `DT_DIR` then it's a file, and if it's `DT_UNKNOWN`, you'll have to stat it after all.

Comment: +1, but `..` is not a link to the given directory; it's a link to the parent. However its reciprocal is one of the two.

Comment: `struct dirent.d_type`, though "not supported by all file system types", eliminates the need of `stat(2)`

Comment: It seems it can be reasonably determined if the `st_nlink` field is properly implemented. I'll use a combination of the two options you presented

Answer (score 2):

The possibilities you've mentioned (as well as e.James's) seem to me like they're better suited to a shell script than a C++ program. Presuming the "C++" tag was intentional, I think you'd probably be better off using the POSIX API directly:

```
// warning: untested code.
bool has_subdir(char const *dir) { 
    std::string dot("."), dotdot("..");
    bool found_subdir = false;    
    DIR *directory;

    if (NULL == (directory = opendir(dir)))
        return false;

    struct dirent *entry;
    while (!found_subdir && ((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL)) {
        if (entry->d_name != dot && entry->d_name != dotdot) {
            struct stat status;
            stat(entry->d_name, &status);
            found_subdir = S_ISDIR(status.st_mode);
        }
    }
    closedir(directory);
    return found_subdir;
}
```

Comment: If you want to optimize the `string`s by hoisting from the loop, you might as well make them `static` too.

Comment: The C++ tag was intentional, although incorrect. I'll update it so it is relevant.

Comment: @Potatocorn:Good point -- actually, it wouldn't hurt to make them `static const`.

Answer (score 0):

Does [getdirentries](http://resin.csoft.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=2&topic=getdirentries) do want you want it to do? I think it shoudl return nothing if there are no directories. I would have tried this myself but am temporarily without access to a linux box :(

Comment: It, of course, returns subdirs AND files. Also, "CONFORMING TO
       Not in POSIX.1-2001.  Present on the BSDs, and a few other systems.  Use opendir(3) and readdir(3) instead."
And filtering the `readdir(3)` output is the only way, because the "has not subdirectories" flag doesn't exist.